# MySQL 5.6 Confusing field value

Tags: mysql

Analyzing the data from my Table:

Here's my sample Query:

```
SELECT * from mytable where myid = 1;
```

Result:

[image]

My Question is:

why this value not equal to `1` display and consider as `1`?

Anyway this value is came from GUID

and the field DataType of this field is `char` length of 36

Actual execution with temp data:

```
set @val = '1f0f69da-b508-412f-bf02-6b506f15a521';

SELECT val from
(SELECT @val as val) as a
where val = 1;
```

Comment: This might help you : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal

Answer (score 1):

MySQL apply implicitly conversion if necessary,

Here you are comparing char column with int value, so MySQL try to convert char column value to int while comparing the value to int like below

```
'1f0f69da-b508-412f-bf02-6b506f15a521' converted to 1

'2f0f69da-b508-412f-bf02-6b506f15a521' converted to 2

'102f0f69da-b508-412f-bf02-6b506f15a' converted to 102

'af0f69da-b508-412f-bf02-6b506f15a521' here it fails to convert to int.
```

So in your example

```
set @val = '1f0f69da-b508-412f-bf02-6b506f15a521';

SELECT val from
(SELECT @val as val) as a
where val = 1;
```

mysql convert to 1 and because of that your query returns the result.

MySQL try to convert string to int until a non digit found.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html)